"I am at a/the library" - which article should I use?
If I am speaking to a tech recruiter overseas, why is the correct way to describe is
"Hi, Jane. This is Katie. I'm at the Library" ?
If the recruiter is someone that doesn't know the library, shouldn't I instead say
"a library?"
In the above referenced context, what is the correct way?

Hi, Jane. This is Katie. I'm at the Library.

Or

Hi, Jane. This is Katie. I'm at a Library.


Why would a overseas tech recruiter need to know that you were at a library at all?

First, articles are very complicated, except to natives. Second, the indicates that it's the usual library you go to, in this case, not that the recruiter knows which library it is specifically.

I would say that 'the Library' implies that the recruiter knows where you work - if not, say 'I work at X Library' (assuming that you mean it's your place of work).

The word library is a common noun, so no capital letter is needed. And three very short sentences is a little excessive: “Hi Jane, this is Katie.  I'm at the library.”

The OP might want to explain why they're whispering, although "I'm in a library" and "I'm at the library" would both work in that case.

What matters is whether your interlocutor knows or not what you are talking about when you say "the library", which is not likely to be the case; have you had the opportunity to exchange with this recruiter before this conversation and manage to explain to him/her that you had something to do with a particular library? If not, "the" is out of the question. You might be talking about a neighbourhood library (or community library) or even a university library; it can even be your personal library if you are one of those priviledged students that inherited a library or constituted one themselves; how could he/she possibly know what you mean?
You can use "the" if you add information that is clearly identifiable. For instance you can say "I am at the public library (in my neighbourhood)", or "I am at my school's library", etc.
In all cases "a" is a possibility, and then the person you are talking to will understand that you mean probably "a public library" or "a university library". "A" would be odd if you were talking about your personal home library, even if you said "I am in a library".

At least in UK English, "I'm at the library" means "I'm in my usual or local library" or just "at a typical library doing typical library stuff". Same as "at the cinema", "at the theatre", "at the beach", "at the park", "at the pub". Although no article is used for "at school", "at church", and a few other cases, that doesn't apply to libraries.

@StuartF It seems that it is also used for a university's library; shouldn't it be so? What other term would you use to say that you are on the premises of a university library?

@StuartF The same holds for AmE. "I sorry, but  I'm at the library/at the dentist's/at the doctor's and can't talk now. I'll call you back."

@StuartF Yes, exactly but also in AmE. Those are all the same exact thing in AmE. What is different, is: in the hospital (AmE) versus in hospital (BrE).
